# Как синхронизировать 4 потока?

Tags: java, многопоточность, synchronized

Товарищи помогите! Написал программу реализующую 4 потока каждый из которых поочередно выводит на консоль сообщение из enum. НО не могу синхронизировать потоки, т.е. после выполнения последнего - первый не выходит из режима ожидания. Хотя я меняю флаговую переменную на соответствующее значение и разблокирую поток методом notify().

```
enum Score {
    ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR
}
class RealScore {
    private static String state = "four";

    public synchronized void One () {
        try {
        while (!state.equals("four")) wait();
        } catch (Exception exe) {}
            System.out.print (Score.ONE+" ");
            state = "one";
            notify();
            return;
    }
    public synchronized void Two () {
        try{
        Thread.sleep(333);
        while (!state.equals("one")) wait();
        } catch (Exception exe) {}  
            System.out.print (Score.TWO+" ");
            state = "two";
            notify();
            return;
    }   
    public synchronized void Three () {
        try {
        Thread.sleep(666);
        while (!state.equals("two")) wait();
        } catch (Exception exe) {}      
            System.out.print (Score.THREE+" ");
            state = "three";
            notify();
            return;
    }   
    public synchronized void Four () {
        try {
        Thread.sleep(999);
        while (!state.equals("three")) wait();
        } catch (Exception exe) {}      
            System.out.println (Score.FOUR);
            state = "four";
            notify();
            return;
    }
}
class Potok extends Thread {
    RealScore rs;
    Potok (String name) {
        super (name);
        rs = new RealScore();
    }
    public static Potok crStart (String name) {
        Potok ob = new Potok (name);
        ob.start();
        return ob;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (getName().equals("One")) {
                for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
                    rs.One();
            }}
            if (getName().equals("Two")) {
                for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
                rs.Two();
            }}
            if (getName().equals("Three")) {
                for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
                rs.Three();
            }}
            if (getName().equals("Four")) {
                for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
                    rs.Four();
            }}
        } catch (Exception exe) {
        System.out.println ("Oshibka1: "+exe);}
    }
}
class Prog268 {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        System.out.println ("Score RUN!");
        Potok ob1 = Potok.crStart("One");
        Potok ob2 = Potok.crStart("Two");
        Potok ob3 = Potok.crStart("Three");
        Potok ob4 = Potok.crStart("Four");      
        try {
            ob1.join();
            ob2.join();
            ob3.join();
            ob4.join();
        } catch (Exception exe) {
        System.out.println ("Oshibka2: "+exe);}
        System.out.println ("Score FINISH!");
}}
```

Comment: попробуйте выбрать какой-то общий объект и вызывайте паузу или возобновляйте на нем. например obj.wait(); или obj.notify();

Comment: @Wlad, не выйдет, другие потоки не будут владельцами блокировки, чтобы использовать notify на них

Comment: @RomanDanilov можно попробовать отказаться от synchronized как метода и переделать на блоки synchronized (obj) { ..... }

Comment: Го из concurrent пакета

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут сразу несколько проблем:

### Нужно использовать `notifyAll` вместо `notify`

Используйте `notifyAll`.

`notify` будит только один из ждущих потоков и далеко не факт, что он разбудит тот, который вам нужен. И когда такое происходит, то разбуженый поток, проверит условие и продолжит ждать. А новый `notify` уже никто не пошлет. И все - у вас потоки ждут на `wait` вечно.

Вы можете это проверить посмотрев стектрейсы в момент, когда програма застопорилась - они будут все ждать на wait.

### wait-notifyAll должны использовать тот же объект

Сейчас все запускаемые потоки используют разные объекты и нотификации вообще не доходят

### Игнорируются исключения

У вас в потоках, ловятся все исключения и просто игнорируются. Это прячет ошибки, и они просто не показываются.

Вот как можно исправить все:

```
class RealScore {
  private static  String state = "four";

  Object sync;

  public RealScore(Object sync) {
    this.sync = sync;
  }

  public void One() {
    synchronized (sync) {
      try {
        while (!state.equals("four"))
          sync.wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException exe) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        System.out.println("Exception: " + exe);
      }
      System.out.print(Score.ONE + " ");
      state = "one";
      sync.notifyAll();
      return;
    }
  }

  ... дальше аналогично

    class Potok extends Thread {
    RealScore rs;
    Potok (String name, Object sync) {
        super (name);
        rs = new RealScore(sync);
    }
    public static Potok crStart (String name, Object sync) {
        Potok ob = new Potok (name, sync);
        ob.start();
        return ob;
    }
    ...

    ...
    Object sync = new Object();
    Potok ob1 = Potok.crStart("One", sync);
    Potok ob2 = Potok.crStart("Two", sync);
    Potok ob3 = Potok.crStart("Three", sync);
    Potok ob4 = Potok.crStart("Four", sync);
    ....
```

Comment: Не сработает, они все так же будут ждать, поскольку не указан объект, на котором делать wait

Comment: Само по себе то, что не указан - это не проблема. В этом случае используется `this`. Проблема в том, что в разных потоках используются разные объекты. Я дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое! и вправду помогло)